Show that $\mathbb R[x,y,z]/\langle x^2+y^2+z^2 \rangle$ is an integral domain.
I was trying to follow the proof in here. I am definitely agree that we only need to show
$\left<x^2+y^2+z^2\right>$ a prime ideal. Since we are in UFD, $x^2+y^2+z^2$ should be not irreducible element so $x^2+y^2+z^2=\alpha\beta$ where $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{R}[x,y,z]$ which are non unit. Therefore, non-zero non unit elements should unit imply
$$\deg(\alpha),\deg(\beta)>0 \hspace{0.2cm}\text{with} \deg(\alpha)+\deg(\beta)=2\Rightarrow \deg(\alpha)=\deg(\beta)=1$$
We can write $\alpha=ax+by+cz$. Also, note that it doesn't have constant term as $x^2+y^2+z^2$ has neither.
Here my question, how we can obtain a contradiction after the following sentences?
Observe that for every $(x,y,z)\neq(0,0,0)$, $x^2+y^2+z^2\neq 0$ (Totally agree!). (Why the following sentence cause a contradiction?) Since we can find nontrivial $(x,y,z)$ s.t. $ax+by+cz=0$, this is a contradiction.

Because for any choice of particular values of $x$, $y$ and $z$ (not all zero) that make $ax + by + cz = 0$, we would have $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = \alpha(x, y, z) \beta(x, y, z) = 0$.

Dear @RobArthan, thanks for your comment. I still don't feel like I understand. How can you so sure about that for any choice of particular values of x, y and z (not all zero) that make $ax + by + cz = 0$? Didn't we say $\alpha$ should be of the form $ax + by + cz$? How can we go further to equate this to $0$?

$\alpha$ and $\beta$ are polynomials in the indeterminates $x$, $y$ and $z$. When we evaluate $\alpha(x, y, z)$ for some particular real numbers $x$, $y$ and $z$ we get a real number. E.g., if $a = b = c$, then $\alpha(1, -2, 1) = a - 2b + c = 1 - 2 + 1 = 0$.

I understand better, thank you@RobArthan. One more thing confuses my mind. Why we can pick the coefficient of $\alpha$ particularly? Is it because the coefficients of polynomials come from $\mathbb R$? I mean we can pick $a,b,c$ arbitrarily in $\mathbb R$ because the coefficients of$\beta$ can cover to get $x^2+y^2+z^2$ , am I right?

$a$, $b$ and $c$ are given by assumption (we are assuming, with an aim to finding a contradiction, that we have specific polynomials $\alpha(x, y, z)$ and $\beta(, y, z)$ such that $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = \alpha(x, y, z) \beta(x, y, z)$). But, then whatever $a$, $b$ and $c$ happen to be, we can find real numbers $x$, $y$ and $z$ (not all zero) such that $ax+by+cz = 0$.

You mentioned that for any values of $a$, $b$, and $c$ we can find real numbers $x$,  $y$, and $z$ (not all zero). However, in the example above, we specifically chose the coefficients like $a = b = c$ with a particular choice of $x,y,z$ in order to make $\alpha(x, y, z) = 0$. I mean $\alpha(1, -2, 1)=0$.

I'm sorry, I don't understand the point of your comment. The coefficients $a$, $b$ aren't $c$ chosen by us, they are given but arise from the supposition that  $\alpha$ and $\beta$ exist such that $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = \alpha(x, y, z)\beta(x, y, z)$.

I've written a very long message here, and it seems like our conversation might continue for a while. I'd  like to send chat invitation.

Sure, that will be fine.

If $ax+by+cz$ divides $x^2+y^2+z^2$ then a non-trivial zero of the former is a zero of the latter since it is a product involving $ax+by+cz$.
